# Write a shell script that asks a user for the absolute path to a directory,

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Write a shell script that asks a user for the absolute path to a directory, the script should test to see if the directory exists. If it does ls -l the directory. If not tell the user that the directory is not there. Save the file as list. I'm a beginner, but I cannot figure out how to get the script to print the ls -l after it confirms that the path is a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Please enter an absolute pathway'

read PATH

if ($PATH == -d)

then
echo  ls -l $PATH

else

echo "This is not a directory"

fi
```

Comment: Don't use `PATH` for one of your own variables: in fact it's best to avoid using all-caps variable names altogether (they should be reserved for 'system' variables)

Comment: An off-topic homework assignment.  How far can we fall?

Comment: Well, at least the user showed some effort - that's at least the main reason why I bothered answering this question. In addition , we're supposed to be a community , right ? Why not simply point the person who's just starting with scripting in the right direction (which is what I've done in  my answer - no more no less ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your big issue is `if ($PATH == -d)` part. It should be

```
if [ -d "$FILEPATH"  ]
```

`PATH` is a special variable that is reserved. If you unset it, you cannot use whatever programs are stored in folders other than your current one.  So , read `man test` about the options and proper syntax of the test `[]` command, and always quote variables

Comment: @steeldriver good catch. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with this script.

- The variable PATH is already used by bash.
- The test itself
- The way to output the result

I would do it that way:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter an absolute pathway"
if test -d $REPLY
then
    ls -l $REPLY
else
    echo "This is not a directory"
fi
```

Comment: I would not do it that way if I were in the class.  The teacher might want you to test it first, and I can see it won't work.  However, I don't want to do someone's simple homework assignment.

Comment: Somewhat redundant, you don't need to `echo`  output of ls because it already prints to standard output. However, good alternative use of test and read prompt (saving up one line of echo).

Comment: @Serg You are right. Edited.